# No additional trips to buffet in canteen, no additional food apart what you have on plate in French?

Tags: alimentation

I am writing the diet rules for myself. I want one of rules say something like this:

> No additional trips to grab more food.

or

> No additional food apart what you have on plate.

I am looking for not exact translation of course, but something like traditional expression which any French person would understand that it is about food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tout simplement :

> Ne pas se resservir à la cantine.

ou encore :

> Ne pas se resservir.

Comment: How about if it is happening not in canteen, but at home? How it fill be in general situation? without taking account where it is happening?

Comment: @AndreyNikulin: You can remove “à la cantine”, see my edit.